# find data between range in matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a rather simplistic example that I would like to learn the best possible solution for. I have a data set:

```
depth = [0:0.5:20];
```

I want to only select 'depth' from a specific range, for example from 2 to 5. I can do this by:

```
d1 = find(depth == 2,1,'first');
d2 = find(depth == 5,1,'first');
depth = depth(d1:d2);
```

Is there an alternative, cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just use logical indexing:

```
 depth(depth >= 2 & depth <= 5)
```